# Q3DBars with grid on vertical walls, how?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, data-visualization, qwidget

This is the plot

[image]

And this is the code

.pro

```
QT      += core gui widgets datavisualization
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.cpp"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DBars>
using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    resize(800,600);
    Q3DBars *graph = new Q3DBars;
    setCentralWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph));
    graph->scene()->activeCamera()->setCameraPosition(30,30);
    graph->setBarSpacing(QSizeF(1,3));
    QBar3DSeries *series = new QBar3DSeries;
    graph->addSeries(series);
    QStringList row_labels{"0", "", "20", "", "40"};
    QStringList column_labels{"0", "", "20", "", "40"};
    graph->rowAxis()->setRange(0, row_labels.count()-1);
    graph->columnAxis()->setRange(0, column_labels.count()-1);
    series->dataProxy()->setRowLabels(row_labels);
    series->dataProxy()->setColumnLabels(column_labels);

//    graph->activeTheme()->setGridEnabled(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

Now to the question:

Can I have grid lines on vertical walls? I mean vertical lines in the picture, same way as in the floor.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Qt documentation to answer your question? That should be your first step.

Comment: Or maybe what you want to do is just not possible with the standard widget(s), so you have to write your own..

Comment: Appreciate if you can give some more hints on how to do that.

Comment: Designing a custom widget to do what the standard one does + what you want, would be far too much for a StackOverflow answer.. But there are consultants available who would happily write such a widget for you. Just expect a fee of $100/hr or thereabouts - or research and write it yourself..

Comment: research where?

Comment: Start by dissecting this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-bars-example.html# then study this class: [QValue3DAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalue3daxis.html) and try tinkering with `setSegmentCount()` and `setSubSegmentCount()` methods. I'd follow this path.

Comment: Normally I would say the same thing: check the docs, study the examples. However, after digging in the source code of Q3DBars and Q3DSurface I don't see a way to add verticle lines at all. There is a difference in the way the axes are rendered - for Q3DBars without and for Q3Dsurface with vertical lines, which seems independent of the axis type. Furthermore, I don't think QAbstract3DGraph is meant to be inherited by any user class, not belonging to the Qt library, nor there are virtual functions of Q3DBars, which could be reimplemented in a subclass to change the way the axes are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Perhaps not possible with `Q3DBars` though with `Q3DScatter` maybe:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <Q3DScatter>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

    auto chart = new Q3DScatter;
    setCentralWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(chart));

    auto series = new QScatter3DSeries;
    chart->addSeries(series);

    chart->axisX()->setRange(0,50);
    chart->axisY()->setRange(0,50);
    chart->axisZ()->setRange(0,50);

    chart->setShadowQuality(QAbstract3DGraph::ShadowQualityNone);

    auto add_bar = [](int x, int y, int z){
        auto bar = new QScatterDataArray;;
        while(z-- > 0)
            *bar << QVector3D(y, z, x);
        return bar;
    };

    QList<QScatterDataArray*> row;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        row << add_bar(0, i*10, 20);

    foreach (auto bar, row)
        series->dataProxy()->addItems(*bar);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```